# How to find the shared properties of any two elements in a CSV file

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
A,rule1
B,rule1
C,rule2
A,rule2
B,rule2
D,rule1
B,rule3
```

Now I want to find out how many 2nd column values are shared by A, B (and A, C and A, D. But A, B as an explanation is enough to implement the rest). What I did was:

```
file1 = open('file.csv', 'rU')
fileR = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')

counter = 0

for i in range(0, 5): #list that contains A, B, C. i.e list = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
 for j in range(0, 5): 
  for k in range(0, 8): # rule list rlist = [rule1, rule2, ...]
   for rows in fileR:
    if rows[0] == list[i] and rows[1] == rlist[k]:
     if rows[0] == list[j] and rows[1] == rlist[k]:
       counter += 1

print counter
```

Here `counter` represents the total rules shared by A, B (and A, C and so on). But I am not getting the right answer. So, the answer should be A and B = 2, because A and B have both rule1 and rule2. Am I doing it right?

Comment: This can be solved handily with Python's `set`s and the `itertools` module: http://ideone.com/pZqnS5. If you use `set`s, you can calculate intersection easily, and `itertools` makes it easy to generate combinations.

Comment: instead of doing this way take a defaultdict whose key is a your list elements and values are rules . then find intersection of a and b gets total rules

Comment: I would create a dictionary indexed by elements of the first column where the values are the set of values associated with that key. To answer your question, you would just have to compute the size of intersection of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

1, convert second field values into `set`s (using set comprehension)

2, use the `intersection` method of `set` to get the ones that are shared between.

3, and get the `len` of the resulting `set`.

```
file1 = open('file.csv', 'rU')
fileR = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
L=list(fileR)
print set(item[1] for item in L if item[0]=='A').intersection([item[1] for item in L if item[0]=='B'])
print len(set(item[1] for item in L if item[0]=='A').intersection([item[1] for item in L if item[0]=='B']))

#set(['rule2', 'rule1'])
#2
```

Comment: Opening the csv file in 'rU' mode can cause problems. As mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader): If `csvfile` is a file object, it must be **opened with the ‘b’ flag** on platforms where that makes a difference.

Comment: simply copied and pasted down from OP, assuming there is a good reason to the do it that way in OP.

Comment: Fair enough. I usually assume the opposite, though, and mention the problem, just in case it is actually an error.